# Calling a dataclass constructor with decorator given only a type object

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass which inherits an abstract class that implements some boilerplate, and also uses the `@validate_arguments` decorator to immediately cast strings back into numbers on object creation. The dataclass is a series of figures, some of which are calculated in the `__post_init__`.

`report.py`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pydantic import validate_arguments


@dataclass
class Report(ABC):
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.process_attributes()

    @abstractmethod
    def process_attributes(self):
        pass


@validate_arguments
@dataclass
class SpecificReport(Report):
    some_number: int
    some_other_number: float
    calculated_field: float = field(init=False)

    def process_attributes(self):
        self.calculated_field = self.some_number * self.some_other_number
```

I then have another class which is initialized with a class of type `Report`, gathers some metadata on creation about that class, and then has methods which perform operations with these objects, including taking some content and then constructing new objects of this type from a dictionary. We determine which fields are set explicitly with `inspect.signature` and explode out our dictionary and call the constructor.

`report_editor.py`

```
from inspect import signature

from report import Report, SpecificReport


class ReportEditor:
    def __init__(self, report_type: type[Report], content=None):
        self.content = content
        self.report_type = report_type
        self.explicit_fields = list(signature(report_type).parameters.keys())

    def process(self):
        initializable_dict = {key: val for key, val in self.content.items() if key in self.explicit_fields}
        report = self.report_type(**initializable_dict)
        print(report)
```

However, this produces an error when hitting `process_attributes`, because the `validate_arguments` step is not performed. Aside from that, the object is initialized as I'd expect, but since the values are strings, they remain as such and only throw an exception once trying to do an operation.

This works just fine and produces the desired behavior:

```
    def process(self):
        initializable_dict = {key: val for key, val in self.content.items() if key in self.explicit_fields}
        report = SpecificReport(**initializable_dict)
        print(report)
```

but, of course, the intent is to abstract that away and allow this `ReportEditor` class to be able to do these operations without knowing what kind of `Report` it is.

here is `main.py` to run the reproducible example:

```
from report import SpecificReport
from report_editor import ReportEditor


def example():
    new_report = SpecificReport(1, 1.0)
    report_editor = ReportEditor(type(new_report), {
            "some_number": "1",
            "some_other_number": "1.0",
            "calculated_field": "1.0"
        })
    report_editor.process()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

I tried putting @validate_arguments on both the parent and child classes, as well as only on the parent `Report` class. These both resulted in a `TypeError: cannot create 'cython_function_or_method' instances`. I'm not finding any other way there is to call the constructor from outside just using the `type` object.

Why is the constructor called properly, but not the decorator function in this instance? Is it possible to maybe cast a `type` object to a `Callable` in order to get the full constructor somehow? What am I missing? Or is this just not possible (maybe with generics)?

Comment: Ok, I've just updated the question with the full example code, I tested this out in a scratch project and confirmed that the issue is reproducible with the 3 files I edited to add. With `report = self.report_type(**initializable_dict)` all of the attributes are initialized, but as strings, and I get `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`, but with `report = SpecificReport(**initializable_dict)` it gets through the `process_attributes()` method just fine and through the print statement and will print the expected object.

Comment: crikey. So, this is obviously something to do with the `pydantic.validate_arguments` decorator. the problem is that `type(SpecificReport(1, 1.0)) is report.SpecificReport` is `False`.

Comment: it must return something *other* than the type - f you look `print(report.SpecificReport)` you'll see it is `<cyfunction SpecificReport at 0x103c581e0>`. This is the problem that happens when class decorators *don't return the class itself*!

Comment: The actual class is available at: `report.SpecificReport.raw_function`.

Comment: So basically, this is a fundamental flaw with the implementation of `pydantic.validate_arguments`, at least as it applies to decorating classes, since it doesn't actually return the class, it returns a function (which presumably wraps a call to the class itself).

Comment: I'm not even sure if `validate_arguments` was every *meant* to work with classes, it just *happens* to work because a class is a callable with the `__annotations__` being the correct signature of the `__init__`

Comment: That explains the `TypeError: cannot create 'cython_function_or_method' instances` when putting the decorator on the parent class! It sounds like it was trying to inherit from a function.

Comment: yep, that would totally happen. Again, it doesn't look like they ever meant it to be used to decorate classes, otherwise, it would have to work like `dataclasses.dataclass` which just returns the class itself. The docs do say it is experimental at this stage. You *could* just use `pydantic.dataclasses` if you just want a dataclass with validation/coercion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fundamental problem:

```
In [1]: import report

In [2]: new_report = report.SpecificReport(1, 1.0)

In [3]: type(new_report) is report.SpecificReport
Out[3]: False
```

This is happening because the `pydantic.validate_arguments` decorator returns a cythonized function:

```
In [4]: report.SpecificReport
Out[4]: <cyfunction SpecificReport at 0x1103bb370>
```

The *function* does the validation. The class constructor doesn't. It looks like this decorator is experimental, and at least for now, is not designed to work on classes (it just *happens* to work since a class is just a callable with `.__annotations__` after all).

EDIT:

However, if you do want validation, you can use `pydantic.dataclasses`, which is a "drop-in" (not quite but drop-in by very close and they made a real effort at compatibility) replacement for the standard library `dataclasses`. You can use change the `report.py` to the following:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import dataclasses
import pydantic

@pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass
class Report(ABC):
    def __post_init_post_parse__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.process_attributes()

    @abstractmethod
    def process_attributes(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


@pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass
class SpecificReport(Report):
    some_number: int
    some_other_number: float
    calculated_field: dataclasses.InitVar[float] = dataclasses.field(init=False)

    def process_attributes(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calculated_field = self.some_number * self.some_other_number
```

Some subtleties:

- in `__post_init__`, the arguments haven't been parsed and validated, but you can use `__post_init_post_parse__` if you want them validated/parsed. We do, or else `self.some_number * self.some_other_number` will raise the `TypeError`
- Have to use `dataclasses.InitVar` along with `dataclasses.field(init=False)` because without `InitVar`, the validation fails if `__post_init__` didn't set `calculated_field` (so we can't use the parsed fields in `__post_init_post_parse__` because the missing attribute is checked *earlier*). There might be a way to prevent it from enforcing that, but this is what I found for now. I'm not very comfortable with it. Hopefully someone can find a better way.
- had to use `*args, **kwargs` in `__post_init_post_parse__` and in `process` because `InitVar` will pass an argument, so extenders of this class might want to do the same, so make it generic.

I had to add `**args, **kwargs` to the

Comment: This is more or less what I went with, though rather than using `InitVar`s I assigned a default value of 0 to each of the calculated fields -- there's some usage of `fields()` elsewhere in the code intended to include the calculated fields, so the `InitVar` won't work in this scenario. Other than that this worked perfectly!